# matching domain names in ssl certificates

Tags: ssl, dns, domain-name, mismatch

I have been going thru X.509 RFCs, and I have issues with domain name matching conventions.

Should the domain name "www.foo.com" match with "foo.com" and ".foo.com" domain names in ssl certificates? please note there is no wildcards.

there is a snippet of section 4.2.1.10 name constraints from RFC 5280, the same restrictions apply alt name extentions.

"DNS name restrictions are expressed as host.example.com.  Any DNS
   name that can be constructed by simply adding zero or more labels to
   the left-hand side of the name satisfies the name constraint.  For
   example, www.host.example.com would satisfy the constraint but
   host1.example.com would not."

Answer (score 5):

unfortunately, if you have a certificate for "www.foo.com", it will not automatically work for "foo.com" unless specified by your certificate provider (or CA). had this same issue before. check the fine prints, something should be listed as "Secures both your www and non-www" or contact their support and ask how it should be done

Answer (score 4):

The section you quote from [RFC 5280 (section 4.2.1.10)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10) isn't about host name matching in the sense of what the client should verify when it connects to the server, it's about what CAs are allowed to issue if they use the name constraints extension.

What you see to be after used to be protocol-specific, and defined in [RFC 2818 (section 3.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) for HTTPS.

[RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) is more recent and harmonises this across application protocols. (It's not necessarily widely implemented.)

More specifically, `www.foo.com` will not match `foo.com` or `.foo.com`:

> ```
> 6.4.1. Checking of Traditional Domain Names
>
>
>    If the DNS domain name portion of a reference identifier is a
>    "traditional domain name", then matching of the reference identifier
>    against the presented identifier is performed by comparing the set of
>    domain name labels using a case-insensitive ASCII comparison, as
>    clarified by [DNS-CASE] (e.g., "WWW.Example.Com" would be lower-cased
>    to "www.example.com" for comparison purposes).  Each label MUST match
>    in order for the names to be considered to match, except as
>    supplemented by the rule about checking of wildcard labels
>    (Section 6.4.3).
> ```

Generally, if you want a certificate to be valid for `www.foo.com` and `foo.com`, it will need to have multiple Subject Alternative Names (even `foo.com` isn't covered by `*.foo.com`).

Comment: Thanks,this make sense, RFC 6125 make it very clear.